# SSAS optimal settings for processing and querying with OLAP site

Tags: optimization, configuration, ssas

I have a cube server with 16 virtual core and 64 GB memory. the average usage of memory is around 45% and CPU usage is about 60% max. We have almost 10 cubes on this server.
We are observing whenever we process a cube(any client) the web application which communicates via OLAP site, queries get stuck. All dashboards for any client hang until we kill the cube processing or it is over.
We were experimenting with multiple settings but any guidance will very helpful as we have restless clients on our head.
Tweaking the ThreadPool\Query\Max thread from 0 to 160 did help if the cube is not running. Also if we process the cube with max parallel =8 or 16 we are able to query the dashboard but slower than expected.
We also add following settting in msmdpump config file :

```html
<ConfigurationSettings>
<ServerName>localhost</ServerName>
<SessionTimeout>3600</SessionTimeout>
<ConnectionPoolSize>500</ConnectionPoolSize>
<MaxThreadPoolSize>160</MaxThreadPoolSize>
<MaxThreadsPerClient>60</MaxThreadsPerClient>
</ConfigurationSettings>
```

Could anyone please help with what is going wrong here and how we can improve it?